# Decrypt using Old private key (pair) and re encrypt using new Private key(pair) in hiera eyaml?

Tags: puppet, hiera

i want to encrypt the sensitive information in a yaml using a private/public key pair. When that key pair expires or changed, the file has to decrypted using the old key pair and re-encrypted using the key pair.

here is my file test.yaml

```
application::user: admin
application::password: passkey
```

I edited using eyaml edit test.yaml and changed to

```
application::user: admin
application::password: DEC::PKCS7[passkey]!
```

Now when i vi test.yaml, i can see

```
application::user: admin
application::password : ENC[PKCS7,blahBlahEncryptedBlahBlah]
```

now what i want to do is,

```
eyaml createkeys
```

creates a different set of public and private keys and i want to re-encrypt the test.yaml file using the new set of keys.

How do i do that?

PS: I don't want to use gpg keyring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

I decrypted to plaintext (base64) using the old keys and then re-encrypted to pkcs7 format using the new keys. Thanks, please mark this one as fixed

Comment: We don't have a "mark as fixed" feature here, *per se*, but in 24 hours you'll be able to "accept" this answer by clicking the check mark next to it.  If the answer had been written by someone other than you then you would not have to wait.